# Uniqueness of non-completable latin square of size $n$

Tags: conjectures, latin-square

It is known that partial latin squares of order $n$ and size $n-1$ can always be completed to a latin square. I want to know if non-completable partial latin squares of order $n$, size $n$ satisfy this property:

- There exists $n-1$ entries with the same row, column, or color.

Is this a known result or maybe a false statement? If not, would it be decent for a research topic?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What about a partial Latin square of order $5$ and size $9$ whose filled cells form a Latin square of order $3$? I believe this partial Latin square is non-completable. Does it contain $8$ entries "with the same row, column, or color"?

Comment: @bof I'm considering partial latin squares with order n and size n. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: What about a partial Latin square of order $4$ and size $4$ with $a_{1,1}=1$, $a_{1,2}=2$, $a_{3,3}=3$, $a_{4,3}=4$?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't think of that.. I actually just found a research by Anderson and Hilton that says essentially the array you found is the only example that is non-completable. (Up to permutations of rows, columns, numbers and permutations of those 3:for example interchanging rows and numbers)